# How do I change a Spinner String Array to one specified by the user?

Tags: java, android, arrays, drop-down-menu

Ok, so basically I am making an Android app with 3 spinners on top and a textView on bottom. The problem is that except for the top Spinner, each spinner is dependent on the spinner above it to decide what is going to be in that spinner.

1 User first selects this spinner.
2 This would populate this spinner with its another array
3 When something from 2 is selected a different array is put here.

Finally when the user selects something from the 3rd spinner, something is shown on textView.

What I want to know is, other than making a huge switch-case to handle each choice, can I use the String from the Spinner String Array item selected to select another String-array.

```
Spinner dropdown = (Spinner)findViewById(R.id.spinner);
    ArrayAdapter<CharSequence> adapter = ArrayAdapter.createFromResource
    (this, R.array.codebases, android.R.layout.simple_spinner_item);
    adapter.setDropDownViewResource(android.R.layout.simple_spinner_dropdown_item);
    dropdown.setAdapter(adapter);

dropdown.setOnItemSelectedListener(new AdapterView.OnItemSelectedListener() {
        @Override
        public void onItemSelected(AdapterView<?> parent, View view, int position, long id) {
            //Whatever spinner item is chosen here changes the next spinner.
        }

        @Override
        public void onNothingSelected(AdapterView<?> parent) {

        }
    });
```

Thanks for any help you can provide.

Comment: Not sure if I understand your problem completely.. But if you want to avoid switch statements to keep your code readable you can wrap it inside a function that takes the string name and returns the name of the array to be used

Comment: not avoid the switch statements, because I was going to put it in a function. But just skip it entirely. I was wondering if there was a function or method by which I could grab the selected spinner item as a string, then convert that in to an identifier that could then be referenced by the other spinners and textView.

Comment: Oh! Then you can use the `getSelectedItem().toString()` to get the string value of selected item